# Checking filesize after download completed IOS4.3+

Tags: ios, xcode, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to check the filesize of a document is correct after I download it to my documents directory. I'm not sure where to check it in my webservice helper file? Or the best method.

I'm able to get the expected file length before it starts downloading. And I can get the length of data sent each burst. I was thinking to add these burst numbers up each time in didReceiveData then compare to the expected length but not sure how to add it up correctly.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
filesize1 = [[NSNumber numberWithLong: [response expectedContentLength]] retain];
NSLog(@"%@", filesize1);

if(requestType == DF_WS_REQUEST_GET_PDF_DATA)
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:self.filename contents:nil attributes:nil];
    self.file = [[NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:self.filename] retain];// file is in .h 

    if (self.file)  
    {
        [self.file seekToEndOfFile];
    }
}
else
{
    [webData setLength: 0];
}
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data  
{

resourceLength = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:[data length]];
    NSLog(@"resource length: %d", [resourceLength intValue]);

if(requestType == DF_WS_REQUEST_GET_PDF_DATA)
{
    if (self.file)  
    {
        [self.file seekToEndOfFile];
    } 
    [self.file writeData:data];
}
else
    [webData appendData: data];

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishingLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
URL = filePreviewViewController.filePath;
NSError *AttributesError = nil;
NSDictionary *FileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:URL error:&AttributesError];
NSNumber *FileSizeNumber = [FileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
long FileSize = [FileSizeNumber longValue];

NSLog(@"File: %@, Size: %ld", URL, FileSize);
}
```

Any help or ideas would be appreciated greatly. Thanks.

Comment: if you really want to check the integrity I would advise you should check the MD5 hash of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just query the file system after the download is complete?

```
[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:&error] fileSize]
```

Make this call when you are told that your download is complete.  According to the documentation for NSURLConnection, your delegate should receive this.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

Comment: Yes, but the question is where to do it.

Comment: Fascinatingly, the [docs for `NSURLConnectionDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) omit `-connectionDidFinishLoading:`, although the headers still document it.  Seems like a major omission.  Everybody affected should provide feedback through the doc page.

Comment: Yeah, it's documented in "Using NSURLConnection."

Comment: Yes, I tried there already but the filesize returns 0. Using this code here which works another view controller. OK, I added the code above, the correct filename and path gets printed but the filesize is 0 in this function.

Comment: Why are you using different paths in the delegate methods?  You use "self.filename" when creating the file, but "filePreviewViewController.filePath" when checking it's size.  All those methods are called on the same delegate